# Proper Shutdown handling of node

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have problems shutting down my nodes correctly. Se the following minimal example:

```
int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "mec_sensor_node");
    ros::NodeHandle _oNH;
    while (ros::ok()) {}
    ROS_WARN("Test");
    return 0;
}
```

If I kill the node (CTRL+C or rosnode kill) the node quits immediately without giving me the chance to do any cleanup. So my question is, how can I achieve this functionality? Using signals is a problem, because I need a function callback. So I thought killing the node makes ros::ok() to fail, such that the node finishes, but that isn't the case, as can be seen via the ROS_WARN command. Any odeas?

EDIT 1:

```
    int  main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "mec_sensor_node");
        ros::NodeHandle _oNH;
        ros::spinOnce();
        ros::Rate _oLoopRate(10);
        while (ros::ok()) 
        {
                _oLoopRate.sleep();
        }
        ROS_WARN("Test");
        return 0;
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291612/proper-shutdown-handling-of-node/) by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-05-18**:
Why is it an issue to have a function callback ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-18**:\

> ```
> while (ros::ok()) {}
> ```

This may be a minimal example, but just to note: without a sleep or `ros::Rate` in there, this is consuming 100% of your cpu, even when doing nothing.

I also don't see a `ros::spinOnce()`, so ROS has no way of processing events. That may be the cause of your issues.

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-05-18**:
@Delb: Probably it may not be an issue, but I couldn't make it to pass a pointer to a signal_handler function. Could you provide a minimal example?

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-05-18**:
@gvdhoorn: I know about the resource problem, just deleted the content to reduce the code, but do you think that this regards my problem directly? However I edited the minimal example, but have the same problem.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-05-18**:
I would have provided a similar example as @gvdhoorn 's link I think this is what you are looking for, and as he said if `ros::ok()` returns `false` the connection to the master are dropped (see [#q253661](https://answers.ros.org/question/253661/cleaning-up-after-shutdown-request/) )

**Comment by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on 2018-05-18**:
@gvdhoorn: Now I see, I couldn't use the ros logging system. Printing with cout shows that ros works as intended. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros::spinOnce()` should be inside your while loop. That function allows ROS time to process incoming events.

Note that logging after `ros::ok()` returns `false` is not at all guaranteed to work iirc. A `printf(..)` might be better.

Btw see #q27655 for what I believe is a duplicate.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2